# use executable stack region in RAM from a shared library

Tags: c++, linux

i just encountered a problem and i don't know if my answer for that is true so i appreciate any help or suggestion.

i'm writing a Pluggable application. so assume i have a method in the plugin class in the shared library like (i created an object from `MyPlugin` class with a heap pointer and simply call this method to give me some information about itself) this:

```
void MyPlugin::getPacketTypes(Packet_types &packets) {
     packets.insert(this->handled_packets.begin(),this->handled_packets.begin(),this->handled_packets.end());
}
```

which i call it from a part of the executable but in the inserting line i get `Signal: SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault)`

and this is how is used it:

```
Packet_types packetTypes;
my_plugin->getPacketTypes(packetTypes);
for (const Packet_type &packetType:packetTypes) {
    all_ok = all_ok && plug(plugin, packetType);
}
```

i just thought maybe its because you can't access stack RAM region of the main application from a runtime loaded shared library, is it true?

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again with a breakpoint near that failure so you can step carefully ahead and watch what happens leading up to that point?

Comment: The thread only has one stack, and any function can access any object on the stack, if given a pointer to it.  It doesn't matter whether that function was loaded from the main binary or from a shared library.  Your bug is something else.

Comment: @tadman yes i did and it happens inside the standard library!

Comment: When that happens use the back trace (sometimes called a call stack) to work your way back to your code and inspect what you are passing into the library call. Usually that's where you're start finding useful debugging information.

Comment: @user4581301 the last code executes(belongs to me) is the insert call in the getPacketTypes function

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch you mean it would help in silly mistakes like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG! stupid!

thanks guys, i couldn't do it without you! cause i was keep thinking about my idea ("you can't access stack RAM region of the main application from a runtime loaded shared library")

the problem was here:

```
 void MyPlugin::getPacketTypes(Packet_types &packets) {
      packets.insert(this->handled_packets.begin(),this->handled_packets.begin(),this->handled_packets.end());
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 }
```

the first argument is a pointer to the wrong object!

it should've been:

```
void ClipboardPlugin::getPacketTypes(Packet_types &packets) {   
     packets.insert(packets.begin(),handled_packets.begin(),handled_packets.end());
}
```

Conclusion: this works perfect so i believe @NateEldredge is right in the comments